# How to get the Label name of the pie chart using angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, ng2-charts

I just created pie chart in angular 8. And I can able to view it. But I just want to get the label name based on the pie chart click.

**Image:**

[image]

Installed

```
npm install ng2-charts
```

Added below lines in html file:

```
<div style="display: block">
    <canvas id="pie" baseChart
            [data]="pieChartData"
            [labels]="pieChartLabels"
            [chartType]="pieChartType"
            (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
            (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></canvas>
  </div>
```

Added below lines in script file:

```
 public pieChartLabels: string[] = ['PayCreditWallet','Paypal','Google Pay','Amazon Pay'];
 public pieChartData: number[] = [1,2,3,4];
 public pieChartType: any = 'pie';

  // events
  public chartClicked(e: any): void {
    alert(e);
  }

 public chartHovered(e: any): void {

    console.log(e.data);
  }
```

When I click the Label (slice) in pie chart I can see click event as alert as mentioned above. Is it possible to get the label name when I click the specific label in pie chart (Slice). Example: In pie chart if I click 'AmazonPay' alert should shows 'AmazonPay'. I don't know how to achieve this. Can someone please help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

.ts file

```
 public barChartOptions = {
    legend: {
      labels: {
        //fontFamily: '"Arvo", serif',
        fontSize: 20,
      }
    }
  };
public chartClicked(e: any): void {
    if (e.active.length > 0) {
      const chart = e.active[0]._chart;
      const activePoints = chart.getElementAtEvent(e.event);
        if ( activePoints.length > 0) {
          // get the internal index of slice in pie chart
          const clickedElementIndex = activePoints[0]._index;
          const label = chart.data.labels[clickedElementIndex];
          console.log(label)
        }
      }
  }
```

.html

```
<div style="display: block">
    <canvas id="pie" baseChart
            [data]="pieChartData"
            [labels]="pieChartLabels"
            [chartType]="pieChartType"
            (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
            (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"
            [options]="barChartOptions"></canvas>
  </div>
```

working link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lrq4ee

Github link for this

https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts/issues/489